# Week number calculation is not correct

Tags: datetime, date

I need to calculate week number from date.

I use this method:

```
DateTime.newInstance(year, month, day).format('w')
```

But this returns week number 1 for 1 Jan 2016. In fact this date belongs to week 53 of 2015.
[image]

Is there any way to solve this? I need this to be European standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives you week number starting out from Sunday:
[How to get correct week number in Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/49355/how-to-get-correct-week-number-in-apex)
.You don`t have to worry about locale settings.

Answer (score 0):

From here :
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=formula_examples_dates.htm

> Finding the Week of the Year a Date Is In To find the number of a
>   date’s week of the year, use this formula:

```
IF(CEILING((date-DATE(YEAR(date),1,1)+1)/7)>52,52,CEILING((date-DATE(YEAR(date),1,1)+1)/7))
```

> You can find the current week by
>   determining how many days there have been in the current year and
>   dividing that value by 7. The IF() statement ensures that the week
>   number the formula returns doesn’t exceed 52. So if the given date is
>   December 31 of the given year, the formula returns 52, even though
>   it’s more than 52 weeks after the week of January.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
MOD(FLOOR( ( CloseDate  -DATEVALUE("YYYY-MM-DD" ))/7)-48,53)+1
```

Comment: I need apex code

Comment: oops, sorry misread!