# Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void ceiling(Integer) from the type System.Math at line 19 column 36

Tags: class

Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void ceiling(Integer) from the type System.Math at line 19 column 36

Trying to add an integer for week of the year into class ?

any assistance would be great

```
public class AddingChildControllerv2 {
    Id parentId;
    public List<Time_Sheets__c> childList {get;set;}
    public Integer rowNum{get;set;}

    public Pay_Run__c Parent {get;set;}


    public Integer weekOfYear {get; set;}


    public AddingChildControllerv2(){
        Id childId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('childId');
        childList = new List<Time_Sheets__c>();
        childList.add(new Time_Sheets__c());
        ParentId=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('ParentId');  

        Integer dayOfYear = Date.today().dayOfYear();
            weekOfYear = Math.mod(Math.ceiling(dayOfYear / 7), 52) + 1;

    }

    public pagereference insertChild(){
        insert childList;

        Pagereference parentPage;
        if(!childList.isEmpty() && !string.isBlank(childList[0].Pay_Run__c))
            parentPage=new pagereference('/'+childList[0].Pay_Run__c);
        return parentPage;

    }    

    public void insertRow(){
        childList.add(new Time_Sheets__c());

    }

    public void delRow(){
        rowNum = 
    Integer.valueof(apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('index'));

    childList.remove(rowNum);
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/49355/how-to-get-correct-week-number-in-apex for an alternative

Comment: Be sure to check the [Apex Language Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_reference.htm?search_text=math) first when you run into method errors.

Answer (score 1):

Apex class has `ceil` method. You have a typo. Please refer below URL for more details

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_math.htm

Answer (score 1):

i found two issues in your code based on error message, there is no `ceiling` method in [System.Math](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_math.htm) class, you should use `ceil` instead of celing then you have to convert Decimal to Integer, working code.

```
Integer dayOfYear = Date.today().dayOfYear();
  Decimal weekOfYear = Math.mod(Integer.valueof(Math.ceil(dayOfYear / 7)), 52) + 1;
System.debug('weekOfYear' + weekOfYear);  // 08:24:36:007 USER_DEBUG [3]|DEBUG|weekOfYear40
```